# Wordpress 2015 Theme: Space on top of page. No related css found

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, themes

If you visit http://sealbeach.thinkbluedesign.com/, you will see that there is a gap which I believe is for the WordPress Admin bar. I tried putting a filter that removes the space but it still shows to those who are not logged in.

This is the code that I used that worked for those who are logged in but did not for those who are not.

```
function remove_admin_login_header() {
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space actually appears to be caused by the margin on the `#topmenu` element. Adding the following CSS to disable the margin on that element should solve your issue.

```
#topmenu {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is within your `#topmenu`.. it has float li...

try adding this in you css file...

```
#topmenu {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin to align it to the top. Add margin-top: -30px to div with css 'top-menuwrapper'. So it becomes -

```
.top-menuwrapper 
{
    background-image: url("images/top-banner-back.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Thanks & Regards
Yogi